# Developer Story tab setting in edit profile & settings

Tags: support, developer-story

In the [Edit Profile & Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) - **Developer Story Preferences**, *Privacy* section after unchecked the **Show the developer story tab** checkbox option, still the "Developer Story" tab is displaying.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Developer Story tab]

Comment: It's still shown to **you**... it hides it from **public** view... try opening your profile page  when not logged in/in an incognito/anonymous browser instance and you'll see what everyone else sees.

Comment: @JonClements So the checkbox option is for, to control other's visibility on my developer story tab in my SO profile?

Comment: That's correct... you can always see it/edit it do whatever with it... what that box does is if anyone else can see it... (note the caveat underneath the box in cases that it isn't public but there's some conditions it can still be seen).

Comment: If you've got suggestions - go for it... I'm just a mod - not staff... so it'll have to wait until the staff on the Job's Team can look at this to review though.

Comment: Since it'd just get confusing hiding the tab from the user whose story it is - maybe something like: add "(private)" or "(hidden)" or "(public)" or similarly to the end of the text of the tab... or maybe an icon prepended (there's room for a "not completed"/"attention needed" one it seems (as is mine)) - but then it'd need to be explained somewhere else what that meant... so - perhaps less straight-forward than imagined.